# Неопределенное количество столбцов таблицы представления

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Всем привет. Модель у меня заполняется из json строки, где для каждого элемента передаются всякие label, type, value и т. д. Также есть свойства row (строка) и column (колонка). И на вьюхе я в таблице для каждого элемента создаю нужный тег (зависит от type), все ок.

Только они у меня идут все по порядку сверху вниз, то есть каждый тег завернут в

```
<tr><td>...<tr/><td/>
```

А можно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы в один tr у попадали несколько td (в цикле)? Например, если у меня 3 элемента в одной строке

```
{ row=0, column=0 }, { row=0, column=1 }, { row=0, column=2 }
```

, то должно получиться

```
<tr><td>...<tr/><td>...<tr/><td>...<tr/><td/>.
```

Или это без таблицы как-то сделать реально?

Comment: Должно быть так: <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>

Comment: @Konst Ну я так и написал. Соль в том, что у меня все tr и td создаются в цикле

Comment: значит надо сначала собрать массив по всем row из json, а уже потом в цикле построчно обрабатывать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может я чего-то не понимаю, но я согласен с Konst, у Вас неправильная последовательность тегов. Похоже, что теги у Вас вставляются в одном цикле, но для построения таблицы необходимо использовать 2 цикла, второй будет вложенный, что-то типа:

```
@for(int r = 0; r < rowCount; r++)
{
    <tr>
    for(int c = 0; c < columnCount; c++)
       {
           <td>...</td>
       }
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Только что заметил, что у меня там опечатка. Да, примерно так я и сделал, по наводке Konst